# TSQL query that would return me the earliest date and the latest date in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a sql server 2008 database that contains bunch of records as well as a date column. The date is inserted automatically when a new entry to the table occurs. So, it contains the date of the record that has been created.

I am trying to run a query that would return me the earliest date and the latest date in this table.

I tried something like;

```
SELECT    TOP(1) DateAdded AS firstdate 
FROM      News 
ORDER BY  DateAdded DESC;  

SELECT    TOP(1) DateAdded AS lastdate 
FROM      News 
ORDER BY  DateAdded ASC;
```

but it only returned the 'firstdate'.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       MIN(DateAdded) As FirstDate,
       MAX(DateAdded) As LastDate
FROM
       News;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use aggregates.

```
SELECT
    MIN(DateAdded) AS firstdate,
    MAX(DateAdded) AS lastdate
FROM
    News;
```

Your query returns 2 results: each works individually though

Comment: thank you for the answer, I marked Jose's answer as he wrote first and I dont want to offend anyone...

Comment: I can imagine a bunch of us racing to answer this one... Lucky Jose :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
    select DateAdded     from (SELECT DateAdded,
           row_number() over (order by DateAdded desc) as rn,
           count(*) over () as added_value
    FROM News
) t
where rn = 1
   or rn = added_value
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```